# What does it mean to “key into” something?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is an excerpt from the book called *I’m Right and You’re an Idiot* (by James Hoggan):

> Those previous frames kept climate change at a distance for many: “It’s happening, but not in my state, or my city, or to people I love.” It’s time to bring the message home and ***key into*** the faith dimension, national security issues and business sector, by outlining both risks and opportunities.

In this context, what is the meaning of the expression “key into”?

Comment: The usually heard phrase is 'key to'. Key into is not much heard.

Comment: My experience has been the opposite: I've never heard "key to," but I'm familiar with "key into."

Comment: Not an expression but a phrasal verb—the "key" in "key into" is a verb, making "key into" a phrasal verb.

Comment: "key to" is utterly incorrect.  the phrase is "key in to" or "key-in to", and quite often "key-in" alone.  it's true that it is often incorrectly written "into"

Comment: Key to success, (Ref.https://finallyfamilyhomes.org/10-keys-to-success-in-life/); Sloth is the key to [of] poverty; just Google it as it is; key to health, key to happiness, etc.  @Fattie, need more examples; it will be given.

Comment: hi @RamPillai - that is a completely, totally, different phrase.

Comment: So, you agree that 'it is not utterly incorrect'? The difference between key to and key into is that, the former is a noun, and the latter is a verb.  'Key to success' is a noun phrase, whereas 'key into' is like "My work is keying data into the format", or 'I am keying data into the format."

Comment: "X is key to Y" is a phrase where Y is likened metaphorically to a lock and X metaphorically to the key that fits that lock.  "Key into Y" is a phrase where Y is likened metaphorically to a lock and we refer directly to the action of unlocking it, without specifying a metaphorical key.  "Keying X into Y" is a non-metaphorical phrase referring to the act of pressing keys qua buttons, with no lock involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To *key into* something is to *focus on* it.

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/key+into):

> To pay close attention; focus: *improved service by keying on customer complaints; keyed into the main points of the lecture.*

In this case, the author is saying that by focusing on the faith dimension, national security issues and business sector, they'll be able to drive their message home to people more effectively.

Comment: I think here there's also a degree of "take advantage of", in the metaphorical sense of "unlocking" potential, but I've not been able to find a suitable definition.

Answer (score 4):

*Key into* means to grasp or understand, informally, to *get* it.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/key_into

The phrasal verb has a variety of connotations that resonate because of other uses of *key* both as a noun and a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Like a key fits a lock, by adjusting the arguments to make them fit audiences experience, opinions, or circumstances, one can engage with them fully to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I can't be authoritative here, but I had always assumed it was a reference to *Foreign Keys* which is a SQL concept.  A foreign key is a pointer to a specific row in a different table.  `citizen.address_id` might be a foreign key into the `address` table if it uniquely identifies that citizen's address.  It gets used as both a noun and a verb.

- As a verb it is used like: "We could key into `address` to get the citizen's country"
- As a noun it is used like: "Does `citizen` provide a key into `address` so we can get the country?"

It refers becoming oriented in a different space, or to an item which makes such orientation possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll note that "key into", in some contexts, could be used to mean to operate a digital keypad in order to gain access.

[image]

This could be the source of a metaphorical use.